# Esscher Premium: Integral Transform Proof

Tags: expected-value, integral

I have some difficulty understanding the following proof and I hope someone can help me with that.

**Claim:** I want to show that

$E_\alpha(S)=\frac{d}{dr} \log M_S(r)|_{r=\alpha} $, where $M_S(r)=E(\exp(rS))$ is the moment generating function of $S\sim F$ and $E_\alpha(S)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} s dF_\alpha(s)$ with $F_\alpha(s):=\frac{1}{M_S(\alpha)}\int_{-\infty}^s e^{\alpha x} dF(x)$.

**Proof**
The proof goes a follows:
$E_{\alpha}(S)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} s dF_\alpha(s)=^{(*)}\frac{1}{M_S(\alpha)}\int_{\mathbb{R}}s e^{\alpha s} dF(s)=\frac{M_S'(\alpha)}{M_S(\alpha)}=\frac{d}{dr} \log(M_S(r))|_{r=\alpha}$.

What I don't understand ist the second equality $(*)$. Why and how can this transformation from $dF_\alpha(s)$ to $dF(s)$ be done like that?

I appreciate any hints! :-) Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a question, are you sure that you have defined $F_{\alpha}(s)$ correctly? Specifically the integrand in the integral?

Comment: Hi Pleb, sorry.. you are right. I have just corrected the definition of $F_\alpha(s)$. It is $exp(\alpha x)$ not $exp(s x)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I've tried to come up with a solution. We know that $\int x \: dF(x)$ is a generalization of $\int x f(x) \: dx$, since:

$$\frac{dF(x)}{dx}=f(x) \iff dF(x)=f(x)\: dx$$
for $f$ being the pdf and $F$ the CDF. Using this result on $F_{\alpha}(s)$, we get:

\begin{align}
\frac{dF_{\alpha}(s)}{ds}&= \frac{1}{M_{S}(\alpha)} \cdot \frac{d}{ds}\left(\int_{-\infty}^s e^{\alpha x} dF(x)\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{M_{S}(\alpha)} \cdot \frac{d}{ds}\left(\int_{-\infty}^s e^{\alpha x} f(x) \: dx\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{M_{S}(\alpha)} \cdot  e^{\alpha s} \cdot f(s),\\
\end{align}
where I've used the first fundamental theorem of calculus for Lebesgue integrals (the Lebesgue differentiation theorem) in the last equation (as stated in a comment below). Therefore we observe that:
$$dF_{\alpha}(s) = \frac{1}{M_{S}(\alpha)} \cdot \left( e^{\alpha s} \cdot f(s) \cdot ds \right).$$
Now, inserting this into the integral specified in your above proof, we get:
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}} s \: dF_{\alpha}(s) &= \frac{1}{M_{S}(\alpha)} \int_{\mathbb{R}} s \cdot e^{\alpha s} \cdot f(s) ds\\ 
&= \frac{1}{M_{S}(\alpha)} \int_{\mathbb{R}} s \cdot e^{\alpha s}\: dF(s)
\end{align}
Giving you the second equality.

Comment: Thanks a lot Pleb! :-) That makes sense! :-)

Comment: In particular, this is a generalization of the fundamental theorem of calculus, to Lebesgue integrals: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem